# ScrewTurn Wiki - How do I display the page namespace in "Page Change Message"

Tags: screwturn

In the ScrewTurn wiki administration pages under "Content Editing" I see templates for the various email messages but I've been unable to find much documentation outside these [samples](http://www.screwturn.eu/Help.AdminContent.ashx).

I would like for the "Page Change Message" to show the namespace of the page in the subject and/or the body of the emails being sent out.

Does anybody know if this is possible.

*note: I'm running Wiki Version: 3.0.2.509*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not possible. All of the available tags are included in the samples you linked.

Comment: The source is available on bitbucket right? Any thoughts on how difficult this feature would be to add?

Comment: It would be quite easy actually.